# None printing in recursive letter pyramid function

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
def letterPyramid(letter, rows):
    count = rows
    if rows == 0:
        return
    elif letter.isupper():
        return
    else:
        return str(letterPyramid(letter, rows-1)) + "\n" + letter*count
        
    pass
y = letterPyramid("a", 6)
print(y)
```

This outputs:

```py
None
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
```

Everything is right in the output except it returns `None` first. How do I prevent `None` from printing at the top of the pyramid?

Comment: Please do not edit your code in such a way as to invalidate existing answers. If you find an answer on your own, great! You can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

When `rows == 0`, you aren't explicitly returning any value, which means that your function is implicitly returning `None`.

You know that at the first level, you only need to print out one letter. So, make `rows == 1` your base case, rather than `rows == 0`. (Treating zero as the base case will print an extraneous leading newline in the resulting string.)

```py
def letterPyramid(letter, rows):
    if rows == 1:
        return letter
    else:
        return letterPyramid(letter, rows - 1) + "\n" + letter * rows
y = letterPyramid("a", 6)
print(y)
```

This outputs:

```py
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions and methods return `None` implicitly, by default, so if you just say `return`, or don't say `return` at all, that's what happens.

There are two places where your recursive function does this:

```py
def letterPyramid(letter, rows):
    count = rows
    if rows == 0:
        return     # implicitly returns `None`
    elif letter.isupper():
        return     # implicitly returns `None`
    else:
        return str(letterPyramid(letter, rows-1)) + "\n" + letter*count
        

y = letterPyramid("a", 6)
print(y)
```

The `None` at the top of your pyramid is generated when the inner-most iteration is run and `if rows == 0` evaluates to `True`.

To prevent this, you can return an empty string, which will concatenate with the rest of your output without issue. However, just doing this still leaves an empty line above the pyramid. This is easily removed using `.lstrip()` on the final string before assignment.

```py
def letterPyramid(letter, rows):
    count = rows
    if rows == 0:
        return ''   
    elif letter.isupper():
        return
    else:
        return str(letterPyramid(letter, rows-1)) + "\n" + letter*count
        

y = letterPyramid("a", 6).lstrip()
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your functions returns without a value:

```
    if rows == 0:
        return
```

It returns `None`. This is why you're seeing `None` printed, because the following adds it to the string.

```
return str(letterPyramid(letter, rows-1)) + "\n" + letter*count
```

Specifically:

```
str(letterPyramid(letter, rows-1))
```

A better approach would be two have an exit condition at `1` rather than `0`. This will avoid a needless newline character being added to the top of the pyramid.

```
def pyramid(lines, ch='*'):
    if lines == 1:
        return ch
    elif lines < 1:
        return ''
    else:
        return f"{pyramid(lines-1, ch)}\n{ch * lines}"
```

```
>>> print(pyramid(4))
*
**
***
****
>>>
```